# Azure App Service Web App access to VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I am running a .NET website web app (App Service) and a separate windows Azure VM running onprem AD Domain controller.There is no connection between onprem AD with Azure AD.I want to access windows VM Active directory (Azure VM) objects under my WebApp/website. Is this possible to access Azure VM Active directory objects through my website ( web app) ? And if yes please suggest the secured way.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use Azure Virtual Network to put your resources (Web App included) into the one virtual network. Then you should be able to query what you need. [Tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/). Or [Web Apps Hybrid Connections](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started/).

Comment: Thanks Alex,There are three options under App Service network. VNET,Hybrid and ASE which virtual network option is more suitable. Also , since I need to access AD ,do I need to give elevated permission (AD permission) app pool account to connect AD or is there any options for secure access under Azure.Thanks once again for helping me out

Comment: @Jhon i think you need virtual network. VN gives you the VPN possibility, so everything will be in the same network. Since you need to access AD, there are some non-Azure related tutorials you may want to use like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.90).aspx) or [that](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/). Basically, ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider should be used, and you should be all set.

Comment: Hope that help - please mark the question answered, if so, for a future reference (that question is often).